# unable to install .vmdk file in windows 7

Tags: vmware

I need to install .vmdk file in order to setup a base environment for a specific application software. Below are the steps which I performed but still I am struggling.

1. Installed VMware player (Non commercial version) in my system and while trying to open the .vmdk file through VMWare player, it started complaining "No operating system found".
2. As next steps, I tried to install vmware-mount-5.5.0-18463.exe which I belive is a free software.But everytime in the middle of the installation,it was showing "The wizard was interrupted before VMware Diskmount utility could be completely installed. Your system has not been modified. Click finish to exit the installation".

Below is my system configuration:
OS: Windows 7
RAM: 4Gb
Processor: i5-4200M CPU @ 2.50GHz
Dis space: 235 GB free.

This is the first time I am trying to install vmimage. Please let me know 
1. Is there anything wrong in my approach?
2. Is there any alternative way by which I can quickly install the vmdk software?
3. Is there any specific reason due to which I am getting the above errors?

Answer (score 0):

In VMware world, VMDK is the image of the Virtual Machine's hard drive. To use the VMDK, you have to create a virtual machine, and add the existing VMDK as the primary hard drive if you want to boot from it.

It depends on your VMDK is bootable or not. If it's bootable, the new virtual machine should be fine. Otherwise, you will face the error message "No operating system found". It's likely your VMDK is not a bootable image.

If you want to browse the VMDK as a hard drive and see its content, add the VMDK as a secondary hard drive of an existing virtual machine. By this way, you're booting from the first virtual machine's hard drive, not your VMDK.